# Como saber se o usuario tem depuração ativada em seu dispositivo?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, android-activity

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que quero bloquear algumas Activity's ou mostrar activity's diferentes para os usuarios com depuração ativada.

Mas não sei exatamente como puxar essa informação para meu codigo.

Atualmente tenho uma class CheckDevice onde verifico se os usuarios estão em emuladores (atraves do *BUILD.DEVICE* e outros) e quero criar um novo metodo para verificar tambem a depuração via usb ou wi-fi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode verificar se o dispositivo tem o usb debugging habilitado assim:

```
if(Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ADB_ENABLED, 0) == 1) {
    // debugging habilitado
} else {
    //debugging não habilitado
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei a resposta na documentação do Crashlytics do Firebase

Caso outros precisem, segue:

```
public void testIsDebuggerAttached() {
    // No good way to test the alternate case,
    // just want to ensure we can complete the call without an exception here.
    final boolean isDebugging = CommonUtils.isDebuggerAttached();
    Log.d(Logger.TAG, "isDebugging: " + isDebugging);
    assertFalse(isDebugging);
  }
```